# jQuery replace img src that's inside a this object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright so I have a link that is clicked...once it is clicked I want the img src that's within  the 'a' attribute to be changed. Here is what I have

HTML:

```
"<td>
  <a href='#' class='flag' name='$files[id]' >
      <img src='".$this->config->item('base_url')."/images/notflagged.png' 
         class='flagimg' />
  </a>
</td>"
```

jQuery:

```
$(".flag").on("click", function(e){
    var fileID = $(this).attr("name");
    var src = '<?php echo base_url().'images/flagged.png';?>';

    // This is where I am hung up, as I want to replace the current src...if I
    // just use $(".flagimg") it will change all src'c with the same class
    $(this).find(".flagimg").attr("src", src);  

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: ok did...any idea why it's still not working even with all of these provided answers?

Comment: That was not going to make it work. just was helping you to have a clean function there. OK the best way to debug it is have it online. can you setup a jsFiddle for it or show a demo online?

Comment: I had $(this).find   in an ajax request and the $(this) in the ajax request wasn't the same as the $(this) outside of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
$(this).(".flagimg").attr("src", src);
```

With this:

```
$(this).find(".flagimg").attr("src", src);
```

Comment: Try `alert("elem: " + $(this).find(".flagimg")[0])`. What do you see?

Comment: This worked...I had to take it out of my success: part of the ajax request. Not sure why...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".flagimg", this).attr("src", src);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is it option for you but maybe you can try to change your HTML something like:

```
<td>
<a href='#' class='flag' name='$files[id]' >
  <img class='flagimg' src='".$this->config->item('base_url')."/images/notflagged.png' 
      />
</a>
</td>
```

Didn't test it but you can try it:

```
$(".flag").on("click", function(e){

  var fileID = $(this).attr("name");
  var src = '<?php echo base_url().'images/flagged.png';?>';


  $(this).children('.flagimg').attr("src", src);    

  return false;
  });
```

Comment: I've also noticed that Firebug complains about this line:  

var src = '<?php echo base_url().'images/flagged.png';?>';

Comment: weird...if I use $('.flagimg').attr("src", src); it works fine..except that it changes all src's with the class='flagimg'

Answer (score 0):

It may be, it is suggested that PHP code don't mix with js to write

HTML:

```
<a href='#' class='flag' name='$files[id]' >
<img src='".$this->config->item('base_url')."/images/notflagged.png' data-src="<?php echo base_url().'images/flagged.png';?>" class='flagimg' />
```

jQuery:

```
$(".flag").on("click", function(e){
    var fileID = $(this).attr("name");
    var flag = $(this).children(".flagimg");
    flag.attr("src", flag.attr('data-img'));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I know everything except that one line works because when I do $('.flagimg').attr("src", src);  it works, however, it replaces all because they are the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Is your src quotes mistype?

change

```
var src = '<?php echo base_url().'images/flagged.png';?>';
```

to

```
var src = "<?php echo base_url().'images/flagged.png';?>";
```